# To take advantage of - vs. - make use of

Tags: meaning, differences

I am writing a manuscript in scientific context and stumbled over the question if "taken advantage of" or "made use of" is the better way to express the following sentence because I have seen these formulation so far only in casual context. At the moment it is formulated as follows:

"Therefore, it is taken advantage of the in Sec. X described motion that lets a point undergo... (further details about the motion)"

I want to express, that I make use of / take advantage of the known properties of the motion to add additional constraints to an algorithm.

Which formulation would you suggest in this context? Thank you.

Comment: One would take advantage of _or_ make use of the knowledge one has of the properties of the motion.

Comment: The English in your sample sentence is too weak for this list. I respectfully suggest that you post instead on English Language Learners.

Comment: Get a life David! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your context, I would prefer "make use of", for 3 reasons.

1. To "take advantage of" something means to make *good* use of that thing (see the definition below), so I'd keep its use to a minimum, so that when it is actually used, it is more impactful, perhaps at a climactic moment along your narrative. I'd use it for something that you really made good use of, not something that you maybe made incidental use of.
2. "take advantage of" also has another meaning (the first meaning in the dictionary search results below), with negative connotations, so I'd prefer "make use of" for simplicity and clarity, lack of ambiguity.
3. Stylistically speaking, scientific papers tend to be more objective, and more level-headed than some other writings (say, some kinds of fiction). So in keeping with this style, go with "make use of" unless you made exceptionally good use of something.

[image: Definitions of "take advantage of"]